# MERGE statement in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Can we use MERGE statement between 2 tables with different columns?

I need to update few columns in target table T1 from source table T2 based on one condition(where T2.Song_code=T1.Song_code).
But t1 has some columns which are not available in Source table. So did not exactly get how it could be used to see if the rows match.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Add create statement of table and query you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SQL***

MERGE INTO t1  AS target
USING t2 AS source
    ON target.Song_code=source.Song_code
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET target.Song_name = source.Song_name -- columns to update
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT  VALUES (source.Song_code,source.Song_name); -- leave empty string (' ',' ') for Column with no value

Comment: MYSQL does not have a MERGE statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
INSERT INTO T2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)  
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4
  FROM t1
 WHERE T2.Song_code=T1.Song_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN with UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T1
       JOIN TABLE2 T2
       ON T2.Song_code=T1.Song_code
SET    TABLE1.col1 = TABLE2.col1,
       TABLE1.col2 = TABLE2.col2
```